# Find all solutions to the polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all solutions to $$x^4-3x^3-5x+1 \equiv 0\pmod{1125}.$$

I was thinking of solving the system separately so we would have 
$x^4-3x^3-5x+1 \equiv 0\pmod{3^2}$ and $x^4-3x^3-5x+1 \equiv 0\pmod{5^3}$
and we solve it for mod 3 and mod 5 firstly and later on with the mod of powers. I believe the idea is correct but I cannot solve it properly.

Answer (score 2):

There might be smarter way of doing it, but basically your procedure appears to be correct.

Solve first modulo $3$, to obtain the unique solution $1$. [Lift it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel_Lifting) to a solution modulo $3^2$. (You will find $4$.)

Then solve modulo $5$, finding the unique solution $-1$. [Lift it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel_Lifting) to a solution modulo $5^3$. (You will find $69$.)

Then use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to get a solution modulo $3^{2} \cdot 5^{3}$. You should get the unique solution $319$.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is sound and for each case you could use [Hensel's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) (=HL), in particular its proof.

Say,

$$p(x):=x^4-3x^3-5x+1=x^4+x+1\pmod 3\implies x=1\pmod 3\;\;\text{is a root, and:}$$

$$p'(x)=4x^3+1\implies p'(1)=2\neq 0\pmod 3$$

so we can apply HL to obtain a root $\;\pmod 9\;$  (we use arithmetic modulo $\;3\;$ in the following):

$$t:=-\frac{p(1)}{3}\left((f'(1))^{-1}\right)=-1\cdot2=1\pmod 3\implies$$

$$s:=1+1\cdot3=4$$

and now we can easily check that indeed

$$p(s)=4^4+4+1=0\pmod {3^2=9}$$

Now, for modulo $\;5\;$ :

$$f(x)=x^4-3x^3-5x+1=x^4+2x^3+1\pmod 5\implies x=-1=4\pmod 5\;\text{is a root, and:}$$

$$f'(x)=4x^3+x^2\implies f'(4)=1+1=2\neq0\pmod5$$

so again we apply HL:

$$t:=-\frac{f(4)}5\left((f'(4)^{-1}\right)=-\frac{385}{5}\cdot3=-77\cdot3=-221=4\pmod{25}$$

and

$$s=4+5\cdot4=24=-1\pmod{25}$$

is a root of $\;f(x)\pmod{25}\;$

Continue as above for a root $\;\pmod{125=5^3}\;$ and etc.

Comment: There is an error somewhere since the solution is $\,319\equiv -6\not\equiv -1\pmod{25}\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, there is a rather silly mistake: for the case $\;25\;$  I *again* took the reduction of the polynomial modulo $\;5\;$ which, of course, doesn't necessarily, and it in this particular case does **not** , fit modulo $\;25\;$ . Fixing this shall bring the correct solution. I'd do it but when I try to edit the answer all the symbols come up as gibberish, as usual in the last 1-2 months in this site, the hell knows why. Thanks

Comment: @idAl Please do read both comments above to my answer.

Comment: Thank you I got the idea. I can fix it  myself.:) @Timbuc